# To Extract text / number from web page using xpath-selenium-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I need to extract a text & number from web page and print in my console.
Xpath to extract those text :

When try doing this, am getting only 0, but these xpath should return numeric & text values associated with it.

Help needed !!

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException

def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver

def lookup(driver,uname,pwd):
    driver.get("URL")
    box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "j_username")))
    box.send_keys(uname)
    box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "j_password")))        
    box.send_keys(pwd)
    button = driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login")))
    button.click()
    button = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fetchCandidateChanges_0")))
    button.click()

    #element = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, "desc"))
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@id='PUSHED']")
    k=element.text
    print(k)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    lookup(driver,"ddd","ppp")
    time.sleep(15)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach for getting the text of all the labels.

**Code**

```
 labels = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[@class="pagebanner"]')
 for label in labels:
    print label.text
```

Comment: thanks Monika, It worked really well.. now i wants to print the name along with numeric value, like. UNREGISTERED : 1 ETC.,

Comment: You can ask the separate question for that. We will be more than happy to help.